# form values are not working

Tags: html, syntax

I have an index.php page in which, there is a login form.

Index.php:

```
<?php include_once("include/header.php");?>

</head>

<body>

<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="header"><!--Header start-->

        <!--Inlcluding Login Barr-->
        <?php include("include/loginBar.php");?>           

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--Header end-->

    <div class="centerContent"><!--Center content start-->        
    </div><!--center content end-->

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php include("include/footer.php");?> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

header.php:

```
<?php session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

<link type="text/css" href="css/mainStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

footer.php

```
<? ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

loginBar.php

```
        <div class="loginBar">

            <form name="Login" id="Login" action="actions.php" method="post">
                  <span class="label">Login</span> 
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="username" value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue;}" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value='';}" />
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="userpassword" value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue;}" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value='';}"/>
                  <input class="loginButton" id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Go" />

                  <input type="hidden" value="loginValues"  name="login" id="login"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

actions.php

```
<?php session_start();

echo $_POST['name']; echo $_POST['password'];

if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="loginValues"){

    echo "HAHAHAHAHA";  
}

?>
```

The problem is, form values are echoed outside the IF block in actions.php page, but nothing works inside this block. That means form values are successfully transferred.

In firebug console, I see an error stating "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

I have tried all options and have placed this line after HEAD tag : 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` , but nothing works.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you echo the value of $_POST['login'] like you are doing with name and password to see if you get anything for login?

Comment: I guess it is because in your `loginBar.php` the `submit` button is not properly closed thus the next `input hidden` is not evaluated in the HTML markup...

Comment: I echoed the echo $_POST['login']; but it prints "Go" instead of "loginValues". Strange. :(

Comment: @MarcB You don't have to be that harsh...

Comment: Well, it sounds like the if statement is failing. Is there a POST field called login? and if there is, is its value = to loginValues?

Usually people use the submit button to check for post, if that is the case, I doubt the value on the button is "loginValues". Just a thought.

In your case, it sounds like the value of the button is "Go" change loginValues to that and you should be fine.

Comment: @user1143254 You need to close the loginButton input element - see the answer below. The fact you get "Go" as a value confirms you don't have the loginButton element closed.

Comment: Thank you @shadyyx , you are right. I have edited the code now. It is working very well now. Actually I got out of my mind that I cannot see this minor bug. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Tad , all working okay. How should I close this question ?

Comment: @user1143254 In the section below this where it lists the answers. If you hover over my answer in that section you should be able to accept it.

Comment: @tad thanks, I have accepted it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is just a typo in what you copy/pasted you have an input that isn't closed, which probably kills the input after it (login in this case).

```
<input class="loginButton" id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Go"
```

should be

```
<input class="loginButton" id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Go" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. All working okay now. I want to close this question. Should I delete it ?